# Polynomial fitting using L1-norm

Tags: c++, math, regression, curve-fitting

I have n points (x0,y0),(x1,y1)...(xn,yn). n is small (10-20). I want to fit these points with a low order (3-4) polynomial: P(x)=a0+a1*x+a2*x^2+a3*x^3.

I have accomplished this using least squares as error metric, i.e. minimize f=(p0-y0)^2+(p1-y1)^2+...+(pn-yn)^2. My solution is utilizing singular value decomposition (SVD).

Now I want to use L1 norm (absolute value distance) as error metric, i.e. minimize f=|p0-y0|+|p1-y1|+...+|pn-yn|.

Are there any libraries (preferably open source) which can do this, and that can be called from C++? Is there any source code available which can be quickly modified to suit my needs?

Comment: Have you looked in to http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl?

Comment: @anjruu Yes I did, it only has least-squares fitting, not L1-norm fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L_1 regression is actually quite simply formulated as a linear program.  You want to

```
minimize    error
subject to  x_1^4 * a_4 + x_1^3 * a_3 + x_1^2 * a_2 + x_1 * a_1 + a_0 + e_1 >= y_1
            x_1^4 * a_4 + x_1^3 * a_3 + x_1^2 * a_2 + x_1 * a_1 + a_0 - e_1 <= y_1
            .
            .
            .
            x_n^4 * a_4 + x_n^3 * a_3 + x_n^2 * a_2 + x_n * a_1 + a_0 + e_n >= y_n
            x_n^4 * a_4 + x_n^3 * a_3 + x_n^2 * a_2 + x_n * a_1 + a_0 - e_n <= y_n
            error - e_1 - e_2 - ... - e_n = 0.
```

Your variables are `a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4`, `error`, and all of the `e` variables.  `x` and `y` are the data of your problem, so it's no problem that `x` appears to second, third, and fourth powers.

You can solve linear programming problems with [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (GPL) or [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) (LGPL) or any number of commercial packages.  I like GLPK and I recommend using it if its licence is not a problem.

Comment: I implemented this approach, but it doesn't work. It fails even for a case when I test it with points which lie exactly on a polynomial.

Comment: @Dženan: I've implemented it too and it does work. :)  What difficulty did you run into?

Comment: I used lp_solve to do this, and I didn't realize that by default variables are non-negative. Setting a0..a3 to be unbounded made it work. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: @Dženan: Gotcha.  I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be doable.  A standard way of formulating polynomial fitting problems as a multiple linear regression is to define variables x1, x2, etc., where xn is defined as x.^n (element-wise exponentiation in Matlab notation).  Then you can concatenate all these vectors, including an intercept, into a design matrix X:

X = [ 1 x1 x2 x3 ]

Then your polynomial fitting problem is a regression problem:

argmin_a ( | y - X * a| )

where the | | notation is your desired cost function (for your case, L1 norm) and a is a vector of weights (sorry, SO doesn't have good math markups as far as I can tell).  Regressions of this sort are known as "robust regressions," and Numerical Recipes has a routine to compute them: http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookfpdf/f15-7.pdf

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the L1 norm is that it's not differentiable, so any minimisers which rely on derivatives may fail.  When I've tried to minimise those kinds of functions using e.g. conjugate gradient minimisation, I find that the answer gets stuck at the kink, i.e. x=0 in the function y=|x|.

I often solve these mathematical computing problems from first principles.  One idea that might work here is that the target function is going to be piecewise linear in the coefficients of your low-order polynomial.  So it might be possible to solve by starting from the polynomial that comes out of least squares, and then improving the solution by solving a series of linear problems, but each time only stepping from your current best solution to the nearest kink.

Comment: I was looking for an existing solution in order to not having to program it myself. ben's and tmyklebu's answers are more what I had in mind. But thank you for sharing ideas!